# not jumping from one activity(layout) to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

unable to find issue. all buttons are working properly and jumping properly from one activity to another but "button About" is not working properly. it must jump to "about activity" ... kindly check the code for issue... "About button" having problem has a comment and is in the last... log, xml is also installed thanks and regards

activity having about button

```
package com.example.routetracker;



import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Select_destination extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button close,main,about,texila,aslam_market,royal_son,comsat;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_destination);

mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.selectdestination);


        mPlayer.start();
        texila=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_texila);
        texila.setOnClickListener(this);
        aslam_market=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_aslam_market);
        aslam_market.setOnClickListener(this);
        royal_son=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_royal_son);
        royal_son.setOnClickListener(this);
        comsat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_comsat_wah);
        comsat.setOnClickListener(this);
        main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
        main.setOnClickListener(this);
        about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
        about.setOnClickListener(this);
        close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        close.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.btn_texila:
    mPlayer.stop();

    Intent i=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
    i.putExtra("place", "1");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
case R.id.btn_aslam_market:
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent j=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
    j.putExtra("place", "2");
    startActivity(j);
    break;
case R.id.btn_royal_son:
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent k=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
    k.putExtra("place", "3");
    startActivity(k);
    break;
case R.id.btn_comsat_wah:
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent l=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
    l.putExtra("place", "4");
    startActivity(l);
    break;

case R.id.btn_main:
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent o=new Intent(Select_destination.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(o);
    break;

case R.id.btn_about:  // for this button i have problem
    mPlayer.stop();
    Intent e=new Intent(Select_destination.this,About.class);
    startActivity(e);
    break;



case R.id.btn_close:
    mPlayer.stop();
    System.exit(1);
}

}


}
```

About Activity Code

```
package com.example.routetracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class About extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button close,main;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
main.setOnClickListener(this);

close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
close.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.btn_main:
    Intent o=new Intent(About.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(o);
    break;

case R.id.btn_close:
    System.exit(1);
    break;


}


}

}
```

XML code for about button

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_about"
android:layout_width="97dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_main"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_main"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_main"
android:text="About" />
```

log file is

```
08-27 08:28:16.752: I/Choreographer(1000): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:17.133: I/ActivityManager(293): START u0 {cmp=com.example.routetracker/.About} from pid 1000
08-27 08:28:17.173: W/WindowManager(293): Failure taking screenshot for (123x205) to layer 21020
08-27 08:28:17.443: I/Choreographer(1000): Skipped 178 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:19.123: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:20.563: D/dalvikvm(1000): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1320K, 28% free 4175K/5772K, paused 287ms, total 327ms
08-27 08:28:20.583: I/dalvikvm-heap(1000): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.468MB for 1319216-byte allocation
08-27 08:28:21.102: D/dalvikvm(1000): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4K, 6% free 5459K/5772K, paused 11ms+25ms, total 499ms
08-27 08:28:21.852: D/AndroidRuntime(1000): Shutting down VM
08-27 08:28:21.902: W/dalvikvm(1000): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.routetracker/com.example.routetracker.About}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at com.example.routetracker.About.onCreate(About.java:24)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-27 08:28:22.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1000):     ... 11 more
08-27 08:28:22.342: W/ActivityManager(293):   Force finishing activity com.example.routetracker/.About
08-27 08:28:22.382: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 121 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:22.412: W/ActivityManager(293):   Force finishing activity com.example.routetracker/.Select_destination
08-27 08:28:22.482: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:22.902: W/ActivityManager(293): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41569f28 u0 com.example.routetracker/.About}
08-27 08:28:23.212: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 246 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:23.232: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-27 08:28:23.373: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:24.403: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:24.523: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:27.279: W/ActivityManager(293): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-27 08:28:27.372: W/ActivityManager(293): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{41569f28 u0 com.example.routetracker/.About}
08-27 08:28:28.053: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-27 08:28:28.512: I/Choreographer(293): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: what is line 24 about.java? show us `activity_about.xml`

Comment: you about button is working but it is crasing in your about activity in onCreate. Just check and it should be fixed. Its a null pointer exception

Comment: Seems like your about layout doesn't have close or/and main button.

Comment: in xml you have button id android:id="@+id/btn_about" and in activity main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main); both should be same.

Comment: check your About Layout xml and Layout  name . Is it exact as your reference

Comment: paste activity_about.xml here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check v.getId() when you click on About button

```
Log.d("ID ::",v.getId()+"");
```

Confirm that you are getting btn_about ID

```
 case R.id.btn_about:  // for this button i have problem

       if(mPlayer != null) { 
          mPlayer.stop();
       }

        Intent e=new Intent(Select_destination.this,About.class);
        startActivity(e);
        break;
```

Comment: Did you check v.getId() in logcat before call About activity